# Avoid giving Wicket's ListView an html element with a body

Tags: html, css, listview, wicket

I'm trying to display a nested Wicket ListView structure as an html *table like* `<div>` structure. This is because I want parts of this table to change it's visibility at runtime and therefore want to add `WebMarkContainers` and then operate on them.
Since this is most-likeley an html problem, I start by only posting the html.

```
<form wicket:id="matrixForm">
    <div class="table">
        <div class="table-header-group">
            <div class="table-row">
                <div class=table-cell></div>
                <div class=table-cell></div>
                <div wicket:id="columnsList" class="table-cell">
                    <div wicket:id="zustLabel"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-row-group">
            <div wicket:id="groupsList" class="table-row">
                <div wicket:id="groupLabel" class="table-cell"></div>               
                <div wicket:id="rowsList">
                    <div wicket:id="erhebungLabel" class="table-cell"></div>
                    <div wicket:id="cellList" class="table-cell">
                        <div wicket:id="cell">
                            <input wicket:id="checkbox" type="checkbox">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Basically I don't wont to have this `<div wicket:id="rowsList">`, but I need an element to map my ListView on.
The generated structure is:

```
<div class="table">
<div class="table-header-group">
    <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-cell"></div>
        <div class="table-cell"></div>
        <div class="table-cell">
            <div>zustLabel</div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell">
            <div>zustLabel</div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell">
            <div>zustLabel</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="table-row-group">
    <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-cell">groupLabel</div>
        <div ><!-- This is the rowsList div -->
            <div class="table-cell">erhebungLabel</div>
            <div class="table-cell">
                <div class="checked" id="cell15">
                    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="table-cell">
                <div class="unchecked" id="cell18">
                    <input type="checkbox">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="table-cell">
                <div class="unchecked" id="cell17">
                    <input type="checkbox">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I marked the `<div>` which I don't want to have with a comment. Is it even possible to generate the same structure in the table-row-group as it is in the table-header-group?
Each element titled with "xxxList" stands for a ListView, so:

- **columnsList** to display the tables header
- **groupsList** to wrap the rows which belong together
- **rowsList** to display the subcategories of the groups
- **cellList** to fill the free fields with check boxes

It's more like an authorization matrix than a data table. I gave the classes the appropriate `display:[table element]` property to make them behave like a table.

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ek679x0o/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

<wicket:container wicket:id="rowsList"></wicket:container>

instead of a <div>

Comment: You just made my day, thank you :-)
Some times the most simple and logic solutions just won't come to mind

Comment: Or use `listView.setRenderBodyOnly(true)`. It is the same at the end.